# Spring Batch partitioning -Queue configuration

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration, spring-jms, jbossmq

We are trying to implement spring batch partitioning.I did an initial study and end up with following questions.

What is the configuration difference between Master and slave nodes i.e difference in configuration xml of master and slave jobs ?

How to configure queues if I am using MessageChannelPartitionHandler?

Whether I can use Jboss eap 5.0 queue as reply and request channel between master and slave queues? If so  how can I configure it my job(A sample configuration file would be helpful)

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically they are all the same; the master coordinates the work but also participates.

The [test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-integration/src/test/resources/org/springframework/batch/integration/partition/JmsIntegrationTests-context.xml) has sample configuration.

Comment: Thanks Gary.I got a better insight from this example